# Create list with for loop for incrementing IP address

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
net = '192.168.1.'
host = []

for x in range(1,255):
    host.append(net+str(x))
```

I'm trying to generate a list of IPs in python with a for loop. Is there a more simplified way to write this? For instance a way to create the host list in line with the for loop, without having to pre-generate the host list?

Comment: If you're using python 3, the `ipaddress` module has ways to do this very succinctly.

Comment: I'm currently using python 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use a generator expression for this, if you intend to consume that exactly once.

```
addrs = (net + str(x) for x in range(1, 255))
```

Otherwise you might want something like this

```
def make_24_hosts(prefix):
    return (prefix + str(x) for x in range(1, 255))
```

Then you can do something like

```
>>> make_24_hosts('192.168.2.')
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f7b364930a0>
>>> g = make_24_hosts('192.168.2.')
>>> next(g)
'192.168.2.1'
>>> next(g)
'192.168.2.2'
```

Or iterate that generator using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a list in one line using a list comprehension :

```
net = "192.168.1."
hosts =  [ net + str(i) for i in range (1, 255)
```